# Which phrase is correct? "worthy of the name " or "worth the name"

Tags: phrase-usage

Which phrase is correct?

1. Any teacher **worthy of the name** knows how to fix the problem.
2. Any teacher **worth the name** knows how to fix the problem.

I've seen both are used in articles. Only one online dictionary, [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/worthy+of+the+name), mentioned that they are the same, so I am not sure if they are identical.

Comment: to be worth something is simply not to be worthy of something. The Free Dictionary is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

They mean the same. I have seen both used by the same writer in the same piece of text.

> The love of Jesus made him seek and save the lost, and if ours be
> worth the name we shall be engaged in the like holy endeavour.

> Love to God, if it be worthy of the name, must be soundly based on
> confidence in Jesus

in "Faith Working by Love", Charles Haddon Spurgeon, August 22, 1880

[Text here](https://www.spurgeon.org/resource-library/sermons/faith-working-by-love/#flipbook/)

Note: I present the above text without any religious intent. It is just an example.

Answer (score 1):

Both are possible, but "worthy of the name" is the idiom that is more familiar to me.

There is another phrase "worth their salt" (salt here means salary, or pay)

The phrases all have a similar meaning.